# Implementing Caching in existing application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

If I am supposed to implement Caching in existing Spring application for all web service as well as database call, what would be the best way to implement it? I mean any of the design patterns and caching mechanism that can be used with other required stuffs.

I would appreciate any suggestion provided.

Comment: Have a look at [Guava caches](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) if this is suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Spring stack, [Spring Caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) could be a alternative you can consider as it will require very less integration and most of the things come out of the box. You can take a look at simple examples [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) and  [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-caching-and-ehcache-example/) too to get a feel of how it works. However if you want more control on the actual underlying cache implementation and the code to interact with that you can roll out your own easily too, though that will require more code to write at your end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using springboot you can use the

```
@EnableCaching and @Cacheable
```

Since Spring Boot automatically configures a suitable CacheManager to serve as a provider for the relevant cache.

You can find more on https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Guru's answer.
You can find more info about Spring Boot Caching on https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.14.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache

@EnableCaching is for configuration and @Cacheable is for trigger cache object.